# Show that a sequence admits converging subsequence

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces, equicontinuity, arzela-ascoli

I don't know how to solve the following exercise. I think I should use Ascoli-Arzelà's theorem, but I don't know how.

> Let $\{ u_n\}_n$ be a sequence of functions in $C^1[0,1]$ with $u_n(0)=0$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, and $\sup \{ \int_0^1 u_n'(d)\varphi(x)dx: \varphi \in L^p(0,1), ||\varphi||_{L^{p}} \leq 1  \} \leq C$ for some $p \in (0,1)$ and $C >0$. Then $\{ u_n \}$ admits a converging subsequence in $C^0[0,1]$.

I'd like to show that such a sequence is equicontinuous and equibounded, but don't know how to use the property in the text. Moreover, that integral makes me think about some weak convergence properties, but I'm still stuck.

Any hint is really appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Big hint:** The hypothesis shows that $$|u_n(x)-u_n(y)|=\left|\int_x^yu_n'(t)\right|\le C||\chi_{[x,y]}||_p.$$

Comment: Still don't know how you get the first equality.

Comment: @VoB Have you heard of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus?

Comment: Of course, I mean: how did you use the hypotesis with the $\varphi$?

Comment: @VoB Let $I=[x,y]$ to save typing - let $\phi=\chi_I/||\chi_I||_p$.

Comment: Ups... so your $\varphi$ is essentially the indicator function in $[x,y]$, right?
With your hint you showed that $u_n$ is equiholder with exponent $1/p$ and constant $C$, but how can I proceed with equiboundedness?

Comment: @VoB Think about it! $|u_n(x)|=|u_n(x)-u_n(0)|$.

Comment: Okay, so $|u_n(x)|=|\int_0^x u_n(t)'dt|=|\int_0^1 \chi_{[0,x]}(t)u_n'(t)dt| \leq C$.  Is it right? –